# Using mongodb in django -- how to form url patterns

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I am going through the django tutorial on creating your first app. I am using MongoDB as a backend. At [part 3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial03/), I had an issue with the url patterns, which I was able to resolve by using this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ex: /polls/
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    # ex: /polls/5/
    url(r'^([0-9a-fA-F]{24})/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
    # ex: /polls/5/results/
    url(r'^([0-9a-fA-F]{24})/results/$', views.results, name='results'),
    # ex: /polls/5/vote/
    url(r'^([0-9a-fA-F]{24})/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
```

)

At [part 4](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial04/), I have a similar issue with this code:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/results/$', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
)
```

I tried this:

```
url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
url(r'^([0-9a-fA-F]{24})/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
url(r'^([0-9a-fA-F]{24})/results/$', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
url(r'^([0-9a-fA-F]{24})/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
```

but I was not able to get the proper view. I get this error:

```
AttributeError at /polls/53286e672da57ad4f09297a6/
Generic detail view DetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug.
```

I assume that these views are looking for the  or  tag, but mongo's ids are not like RMDBs, so it fails if you don't change it.

How do I get mongo to work with their code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out... from https://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#adding-some-templates

Make the url patterns like this:

```
url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
url(r'^(?P<pk>[a-z\d]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
url(r'^(?P<pk>[a-z\d]+)/results/$', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
url(r'^(?P<poll_id>[a-z\d]+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
```